# exclude subdomains from .htaccess for wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, multisite

I have a plesk server and its configured to launch Roundcube on webmail.domain.com . Also I configured my Wordpress as a multi-site to react as with anysubdomain.domain.com, but it stops the webmail subdomain to work. How do I exclude that subdomain (webmail) from been cached by Wordpress ?

This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

to EXCLUDE (sub)domains in your ".htaccess" - file, you would use something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^webmail\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```